# IList to EntityCollection with reflection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, reflection, entity-framework-4

In an application that I write, I build the interface via reflection from the data context. Displaying the values is no problem, but creating the item collections and assigning values via reflection does not work.

Here is the code in question:

```
var listItemType = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First();
// See remark #1
var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { listItemType });
var assocItems = Activator.CreateInstance(listType) as IList;
var listSelector = EditorPanel.FindControl(property.Name) as PropertyListBox;
if (listSelector != null)
{
    foreach (var selectedItem in listSelector.SelectedItems)
    {
        assocItems.Add(selectedListItem);
    }
}
// See remark #2
property.SetValue(itemToUpdate, assocItems, null);
```

**Remark #1:**

I tried to change the line to `var listType = typeof(EntityCollection<>).MakeGenericType(new[] {listItemType});` and then cast `assocItems` to IListSource. Instead of `assocItems.Add()` I called `assocItems.GetList().Add()`, but that resulted in an `InvalidOperationException`:

> The object could not be added to the
>   EntityCollection or EntityReference.
>   An object that is attached to an
>   ObjectContext cannot be added to an
>   EntityCollection or EntityReference
>   that is not associated with a source
>   object.

**Remark #2:**

Here I need to convert the `IList` to an `EntityCollection<T>` somehow.

Comment: Why so complex code? What are you trying to do? This must be possible without reflection.

Comment: The idea for the application is, that whenever something is changed on the data, only the Entity Framework assembly and database have to be changed, the UI will adapt to the assembly and the types. Therefore, the same application can be used on many instances with different upgrade data models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of preparing a list and setting it to the entity collection can you call the Add function on the EntityCollection property with each item? You could use reflection to call the method if you do not know what the type of T is for a proper cast.

Answer (score 0):

R Kitty had the right answer, but another problem came up, because one can't just set a property of type `EntityCollection`. Here's the full trick for anyone trying to do the same thing:

```
var listItemType = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First();
var clearMethod = property.PropertyType.GetMethod("Clear");
var addMethod = property.PropertyType.GetMethod("Add");
var listSelector = EditorPanel.FindControl(property.Name) as PropertyListBox;
if (listSelector != null)
{
    clearMethod.Invoke(property.GetValue(itemToUpdate, null), null);
    foreach (var selectedItem in listSelector.SelectedItems)
    {
        addMethod.Invoke(property.GetValue(itemToUpdate, null), new[] {selectedItem});
    }
}
```